# manupulate title using pipe in html-Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm building rows and columns using "ngx-datatable". for one of the row item I need to use a pipe to capitalize the item. I know how to do it in .js. But I must need to do it in html for some reason. I don't have any idea how to do that in html. Can any one help?

Thanks in advance..

```js
  private getRows() {
    this.rows = [];
    for (const item of this.list) {

      const rowObject: any = {
        date: item.date, 
        method:item.method,                    status:item.status),
        detail: item.paymentId
      };

      
      this.rows.push(rowObject);
    }


  }
```

```html
 <ngx-datatable
    [rows]="rows"
    [columns]="columns"
    *ngIf="rows.length">
  </ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: If you don't want to do it in `js` the other option is `css`: `text-transform: capitalize;`.

Comment: Not exactly to "capitalize". I must need to use a pipe for one of the row item

Comment: You can pass your pipe in the row template mentioned [here](https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/content/api/detail/inputs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the output of your row template.

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns" *ngIf="rows.length">

  <ngx-datatable-column name="Date">
    <!-- condition logic here -->
    <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      <!-- value with a pipe -->
      {{value | date}}
    </ng-template>

  </ngx-datatable-column>

</ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: condition means what kind of condition?

Comment: Whatever condition you want to apply.  ex. `*ngIf="row.$$index == 2"` - if row index is 2 etc